# How to update application scope variable in all deployed servers?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web, web-deployment, nlb

I have deployed my application in 6 different application servers using NLB. We have a list in application scope. When updating list from server 1, it is not reflecting in other servers.

How to update the other servers application scope variables?

How to update the other servers static variables?

Thanks - kp

Comment: Honestly your application is deployed and the Session Management is overlooked ? How are you using this list?

Comment: Application variables scope will to be only to requests to that particular server . If your servers are not sticky then I don't see any solution for storing except external sources or client side(cookies,viewstate,querystring)

Comment: i am using scale out server for session management. That list has values to load dropdown. this dropdown will display 5 pages. So i kept the list in application to avoid db hits to get the list for each page.

Comment: Just had a glance at these scaleout servers and it should be working. One of the debugging points you might have to start is check if the session id is same for these requests , if that is working , then the list might be having another reference and is getting nullified somewhere.